# Selecting Max or Min Results

Tags: sql, oracle, select, max, min

I have an query that has been giving me trouble.  I think there is probably an easy solution, but please help me where you can!

My main problem is that there are often multiple emails per cust_id.  There are unique identifiers such as a sequence number (seq_no) and updated date (updated_date).  I only want the newest email address to show for any one customer.

By the way, this is an oracle DB.

Any suggestions?

```
SELECT DISTINCT
table1.indident_id, 
table1.incident_detail_id, 
table1.incdent_entered_date, 
table1.entering_employee, 
table2.EMAIL
FROM table1
left outer join table2 on table1.cust_id=table2.cust_id
WHERE table1.incdent_entered_date>=current_date-4
AND table1.table1.incident_detail_id=(select min(table1.table1.incident_detail_id)from table1)
AND table2.EMAIL NOT IN ('NONE','none','none@none.com')
AND table2.EMAIL like '%@%'
```

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2631230/how-to-select-the-record-contains-maxsome-field-within-groupgroup-by

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of options.  The most efficient is to use an analytic function.

```
SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT table1.indident_id, 
           table1.incident_detail_id, 
           table1.incdent_entered_date, 
           table1.entering_employee, 
           table2.EMAIL,
           row_number() over (partition by table2.cust_id
                                  order by table2.updated_date desc) rnk
      FROM table1 
           left outer join table2 on table1.cust_id=table2.cust_id
     WHERE table1.incdent_entered_date>=current_date-4
       AND table1.table1.incident_detail_id=(select min(table1.table1.incident_detail_id)
                                               from table1)
       AND table2.EMAIL NOT IN ('NONE','none','none@none.com')
       AND table2.EMAIL like '%@%'
  )
 WHERE rnk = 1
```

Less efficiently, but something that will work in just about any database, would be to do something similar to what you're currently doing with the `incident_detail_id` subquery

```
    SELECT table1.indident_id, 
           table1.incident_detail_id, 
           table1.incdent_entered_date, 
           table1.entering_employee, 
           table2.EMAIL
      FROM table1 
           left outer join table2 on table1.cust_id=table2.cust_id
     WHERE table1.incdent_entered_date>=current_date-4
       AND table1.table1.incident_detail_id=(select min(table1.table1.incident_detail_id)
                                               from table1)
       AND table2.update_date = (SELECT MAX(t2_inner.update_date)
                                   FROM table2 t2_inner
                                  WHERE t2_inner.cust_id = table1.cust_id)
       AND table2.EMAIL NOT IN ('NONE','none','none@none.com')
       AND table2.EMAIL like '%@%'
```